# accessoryType on cell not changing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a list of products in a TableView. The list is populated by a WCF call. I can see in the log that the products are loading with the correct values. One of the values is a boolean called Bought. I would like to use this to show (with a checkmark on the tableviewCell), if the product is bought or not

Here i load the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProductCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    id prod = [_productList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [prod ProductName];
    NSString *stringAmount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [prod Amount]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = stringAmount;
    if (![prod Bought]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }


    return cell;
}
```

And here i change the value

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    [self markBought];
    [tableView reloadData];
    [self reloadInputViews];
}
```

The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`method works (i can see the value changing in the database)
But the checkmark is always on -

I suspect I'm loading the Accessorytype wrong - but I can't really see how to do it differently.

Comment: A product comes out like this:
`<a:Product><a:Amount>1</a:Amount><a:Bought>false</a:Bought><a:ProductId>1</a:ProductId><a:ProductName>Æg</a:ProductName></a:Product>``

Comment: Does `[prod Bought]` return a scalar (e.g. `BOOL`) or an object (e.g. `NSNumber`) ? In the latter case, you probably have to check `if (![[prod Bought] boolValue]) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[prod Bought]` return a `NSNumber` object, therefore you have to replace

```
if (![prod Bought]) ...
```

by

```
if (![[prod Bought] boolValue]) ...
```

Comment: My checkmarks aren't updating. I have to leave the list and enter it again to see the updated checkmarks. 
Do I need to do anything other than [[self tableview reloadData] in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`method?

Comment: Solved it.
Needed  `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }`